# UDP socket Python

Tags: python, sockets, udp

I have the following source code:

```
import socket

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM) # UDP
s.bind(('', 9800))
try:
    while True:
        data, addr = s.recvfrom(256) #buffer size is 256 bytes
        print data, adrr
finally:
    s.close()
```

And when I execute it I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "socket.py", line 1, in 
     import socket
   File "C:\Users\Victor\Desktop\socket.py", line 3, in 
     s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM) # UDP
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'AF_INET'
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 7):

Change the name of your script. It is trying to import itself.

Comment: Stupid mistake! Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Your `socket.py` clashes with the stdlib `socket` module. You should rename it.

Answer (score 1):

You can't name your Python source file the same as a module you are importing. The Python interpreter will import your own source file.